# How do I implement a minimal access control for a private Web App?

Tags: security, authentication, web

I'm developing a **web application** with Python/Bottle having **only one user** (me), running on my **own (https) server**. I would like to prevent someone from stumbling over my application and abusing it, but at the same time I want to **conveniently use it** from my iPhone. Entering a **password each time is not an option** for me.

I was thinking along the lines of either having a complex url or adding some token to the url and to bookmark this page.

Would this provide the minimal security I'm looking for? Are there better options?

Comment: Putting credentials into the URL is not considered security best practice.

Comment: As mentioned above, adding security tokens on URLs is discouraged. Is there an issue with implementing a simple authentication scheme (username/password login) and using [cookies](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#tutorial-signed-cookies) that never expire?

Comment: @UziGoozie. This sound like a pragmatic approach. I will apply this. Just looked-up implementation and its seems to be fairly easy. Thx. PS: I will edit the question. Feel welcome to add this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a small project and maybe what you are suggesting might actually work on protecting your web application, but here is a bit of explanation on your current solution.

What you are suggesting with the "complex url" sounds like "security through obscurity": it does not solve the problem that your web application has no security mechanisms, but makes it a lot harder to access your application's functionality. Generally, people consider "security through obscurity" as no security, as an determined attacker will find a way to access the complex URLs eventually, in your case. As mentioned in the comments above, it is also discouraged to add security/session tokens in URLs.

Although, in your use-case these might just work, I would say both suffer in two "attack" scenarios:

1. getting you phone stolen, or leaving it unattended, anyone will be able to see your browsing history
2. [Cross-domain Referer leakage](https://portswigger.net/kb/issues/00500400_cross-domain-referer-leakage)

If you can accept the risk of the above, you will be good.

To me, it seems it is not that hard to implement a minimal login functionality with Bottle and set the cookies to "never" expire. Below you will find a minimal example (or if you are open to using plugins, you can try [Cork](https://cork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from bottle import route, run, request, redirect, response
import json
import os
import functools
import time

secret = os.urandom(32).hex()

USERNAME = "admin"
PASSWORD = "admin"
COOKIE_NAME = "session-cookie"
HTTPS = True

def verify_cookie() -> bool:
    return request.get_cookie(COOKIE_NAME, secret=secret) == USERNAME

def verify_creds(username : str, password : str) -> bool:
    return username == USERNAME and password == PASSWORD

def set_cookie(username : str):
    in_ten_years_from_now = int(time.time()) + 10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60
    response.set_cookie(COOKIE_NAME, username, secret=secret, expires = in_ten_years_from_now, secure=HTTPS, httponly=True)

def require_authorized(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if not verify_cookie():
            redirect("/login")
        return func(*args,**kwargs)
    return wrapper


@route('/', method='GET')
@require_authorized
def index():
    return f"Welcome, {request.get_cookie(COOKIE_NAME, secret=secret)}"

@route('/login', method=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return "Welcome to the login page"
    else:
        username,password = request.forms.get("username"), request.forms.get("password")
        if verify_creds(username,password):
            set_cookie(username)
            redirect("/")
        else:
            return "Invalid creds, pls retry"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```